# Is it possible to check using nagios, if a group X is denied access a particular file/folder in Windows

Tags: windows, group-policy, nagios

This is basically a GPO key that has been applied and need to check if the key is in place/working which involves restricting a group of users from accessing a particular file or folder using a monitoring system like Nagios.

I already plan to write a script to check this on the windows server. But I need to check what  tool needs to be used for this and where I will need to look for the data

Comment: I can't think of any built-in plugins to do this, but you can easily write your own scripts.  Compose a script to perform this test with your favorite language.

Comment: @Zoredache I have updated my requirement.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the data from your windows system to the nagios server?  There are a couple solutions.  You basically have to install an agent on the Windows box that is either used to pull the data or push the data to the nagios server.  For example nsclient++

Comment: No I am aware of this, but I need to know the windows tool to check if the policy has been set as per the requirement.

Comment: So you are not looking to know if the system is in your desired state, you are wanting to look at group policy results?  Maybe run `gpresult.exe /x filename`, then parse the xml and see if your policy is being applied?